# Adding Sliding Layer to a Fragment not working

Tags: android

i am using this library to create a sliding pane.

https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib

Basically it is a sliding menu. Now, when I am using it in an activity, it is working fine. I am adding it dynamically like this :-

```
slidingPane = (SlidingLayer) View.inflate(this,R.layout.sliding_pane, null);
swipeText = (TextView) slidingPane.findViewById(R.id.swipeText);
parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout); // Main Layout
parentLayout.addView(slidingPane);
```

and it is simply used like this, lets say on a button click :-

```
slidingPane.openLayer(true);
```

When i am trying to inflate it in a Fragment class using the same steps above, it is not showing. This is what i am doing in `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
AUslidePane = (SlidingLayer) View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.sliding_pane, null);
AUswipeText = (TextView) AUslidePane.findViewById(R.id.swipeText);
parentLayoutdashboardAU = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parentLayoutdashboardAU);
parentLayoutdashboardAU.addView(AUslidePane);
```

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here ?

Comment: Show your Fragment class code...

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur - Edited code. Please check

Comment: this line give error >> AUslidePane = (SlidingLayer) View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.sliding_pane, null);   ???

Comment: No, it doesn't. There is no error. Please use the git library. It is working in an Activity, but not in fragments

Comment: It Worked without any problems for me.. please check the layout order ..may be it not working because of the view is hidden behind some views( It was my problem )